# translating all values in a column in a database from one language to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-translate

I have a table with fishnames in swedish, looks something like this:

FishID | SwedishName | Habitat

I have all the swedish names for every fish but i want the english name aswell, I want it to look like this:

FishID | SwedishName | EnglishName | Habitat

Is there any way to translate the swedish name of every fish to english and insert it in the 'EnglishName' column?

Comment: There is no magic database call to translate things for you.  Have you begun to formulate an approach on how you might be able to make these translations?  Do you have the translations already and you just need to somehow update the database?

Comment: sure. get a swedish/english dictionary and start looking up words.

Comment: Try this, come back with another question if you run into problems: [Using the free Bing translation APIs](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis)

Comment: Most likely you end up with bad translations (IMO) while using Google translate for specific fish names to translate. However if you still want to do that, check: https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started and php `cURL`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to translate the swedish name of every fish to
>   english and insert it in the 'EnglishName' column?

Unless you use an API your need to insert the english version into your DB, if you have a list or array ready to insert it would be trival but if you dont you might have todo something like this, where you select all the rows and then create a basic form table where you can list and put the English equivalent.

```
<?php 
//connect
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fish_db', 'username', 'password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Sorry there is a problem with the database connection :' . $e->getMessage();
}

//update if POST'ed form
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    foreach($_POST['EnglishName'] as $key => $value){
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE fish_table 
                              SET EnglishName = :EnglishName 
                              WHERE FishID=:FishID');

        $stmt->bindValue(':EnglishName', $value);
        $stmt->bindValue(':FishID', $key);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}

//select rows
try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM fish_table WHERE EnglishName = ""');
    $stmt->execute();
    $fishs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
    <?php foreach($fishs as $fish):?>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="swedish[<?php echo $fish['FishID']?>]" value="<?php echo $fish['SwedishName']?>"></td>
            <td width="50%"><input type="text" name="english[<?php echo $fish['FishID']?>]" value=""></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Or use phpmyadmin ;p